# OSMnx list of network types

Tags: osmnx

I searched through the documentation and examples but could not find a complete list of network types.  I looked at the OSM API documentation as well.  I know a few like "all", "drive", "bike", "walk" but is there a complete list somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.graph). There is a list of possible `network_type` arguments in the docstring of every `graph_from_whatever` function. For example:

> network_type (string) – what type of street network to get if custom_filter is None. One of ‘walk’, ‘bike’, ‘drive’, ‘drive_service’, ‘all’, or ‘all_private’.